# Installing angular 1.5 typings

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings, angularjs-1.5

### Update 3/26/2017

I now use `npm install @types/angular` with TypeScript 2.0 and the experience so far has been *much smoother* than `typings` was.

### Original

I have an Angular 1.5 project using ES6 modules and Webpack, which is very similar to [this starter project](https://github.com/kitconcept/webpack-starter-angular).

I am attempting to install [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) for Angular 1.5. I've used `tsd` in the past, but this is the first time I've tried to use the newer `typings` manager.

When I try `typings install angular` I get:

```
"Unable to find "angular" ("npm") in the registry."
```

When I run `typings search angular` I see a result `NAME: angular, SOURCE: dt`.

When I try `typings install angular dt~angular` I get:

```
"Attempted to compile "angular" as an external module, but it looks like a global module."
```

However when I look at [DefinitelyTyped/angular.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts) I see that although it does declare a global `angular` variable, it also declares a module `"angular"`, as many of the DefinitelyTyped definitions do to support UMD.

How can I get this to work with typings? Or should I just stick with `tsd`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I see that although it does declare a global angular variable, it also declares a module "angular"

The whole file is still global. i.e. there can be only one `declare module "angular"`. Hence you still need to global flag (`typings install dt~angular --global`)

Comment: If jQueryStatic warning appears, try: typings install dt~jquery --global --save

Comment: Since Typings are deprecated, use npm for the purpose, like in the next answer

Answer (score 7):

with TypeScript 2.0, you can make `package.json` file like this:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/angular": "^1.5.6",
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, you can just run `npm install`!